# How to deploy JavaFX project using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, javafx-2, fxml

I am writing a program which I would like to deploy as both desktop and android applications. I want to use JavaFX 2.0 with FXML for the desktop side of things. I want to work entirely in Android Studio. Right now, I am just concerned about producing an desktop executable (for Windows to start with) for my JavaFX program. I'd like to produce an `.exe` file if possible, or at least a `.jar`.

To clarify, I am **not** asking how to go about deploying/compiling an existing JavaFX project for Android. I know there exists something called JavaFXPorts for that. I just want to *compile and deploy a regular JavaFX program using Android Studio, totally ignoring anything to do with Android for now*. (If JavaFXPorts somehow helps with this, then by all means, please show me how).

So far, I've managed to create a [regular Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects) in Android studio, add in some ['hello world' JavaFX files](http://javajdk.net/tutorial/javafx-8-hello-world-for-eclipse/), and [(sort of) deploy the program](http://ryansblog.jptech.ca/2012/12/javafx-and-gradle.html).

There are many questions squeezed into this one SO question.
I don't know where to put my FXML files so that my final Jar file can find them. I think I have to get gradle to copy them to the build directory, but I don't know what the standard way of doing this is. Do I need to put my FXML files in a 'resources' or 'assets' directory? How do I write a gradle script to copy the files over? Should I refer to the FXML files directly, or through the resources system?

It seems that IntelliJ does this automatically using [compiler resource settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421325/how-to-convert-a-normal-java-project-in-intellij-into-a-javafx-project), but Android Studio is missing this functionality (probably because it assumes I only want to create an Android app, so only need to use the Android resource system).

Just as a reminder, the entire relevant part of my project is located in a 'Java Library' **module** in the Android Studio project.

I've created an **test project which I've uploaded here**: https://github.com/Aralox/Android-Studio-FXML-Executable-JavaFX-Project

Here are a few screenshots:

Complaints about a missing 'resources/main' directory. This probably has something to do with the JavaFX gradle script I copied from [here](http://ryansblog.jptech.ca/2012/12/javafx-and-gradle.html). I manually added in this directory for the program to compile (super hacky).
[image: Missing 'resources/main' directory???]

My program couldn't find the FXML file it was looking for because of a change in working directory (hacky way of finding the FXML because using `getClass().getResource()` did not work, because the FXML was not copied to the output directory).
[image: FXML file location troubles in final deployed jar]

Final program working after I manually copied the FXML file into the build directory (and told the program where to find it).
[image: Running application with 'hacked in' FXML file]

I know this was a long question, but I hope I've made my essential problem clear. The 'child' questions are just problems I encountered in my attempt to find a solution. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: About fxml you can put them under resources/fxml/example.fxml.Then you can access fxml files like  getClass().getResource(example.fxml)