# Are there any standard for JavaFX directory/package structure?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm just starting to develop a javafx application, and i'm reading [some tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm). In those tutorials there are no mentions to good practices or propper (standard) ways to structure your app. Even though FXML documents provide a separation of the presentation layer, `.fxml` and `.css` files are stored in the same directory as `.java` files, and since I come from developing using frameworks like django and rails, the lack of a standard structure or layer separation disturbs me.

Is there any propper (more *MVCish*) way to structure a project? or is the one proposed by those tutorials the propper way?

thanks for your help, and notice that I'm not implying that that way is not correct. It's only that I'm used to the kind of structure proposed by popular web frameworks, and I would like to work like that with this new app (which is my grade project, btw).

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/19603055/1925961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best Solution for this.

But an example way is:

Create a properly named package structure for java files.

**Main java files** (example: de.kogs.testapp)

**Controller java files** (example de.kogs.testapp.controller)
and so on.

For **fxml** files:

example

```
fxml/main.fxml

fxml/slideouts/userSlide.fxml
```

Your pictures and **css** Files:

```
css/main.css

css/images/logo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually have two packages: one for the FXML, CSS and controller files (`ui`) and another for the underlying Java code (could be named `core`, or something specific to the app like `analysis` or `evaluator`).

However, having all the UI files lumped into one package could become unwieldly, so one could (instead or additionally) split these files by type (into separate FXML, CSS and controller packages) as in [Marcel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811599/marcel)'s answer. Similarly, one could split the package containing the underlying Java code further too.