# How to load FXML file which is out of *.jar file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

this is my first post on Stack, I was looking for answer on my question, but I haven't found anything useful.
I'm learning Java, so be gentle ;)

My problem is, that I don't want to make One file with everything in "jar". I must load FXML file, which is out of *.jar file.
For example:
I'm making FXML file which is in my JavaFXMLApplication folder, I run "JavaFXApplication.jar" file and this Application use FXML which I just made.

I hope I describe it clearly :)

**EDIT:**
I have found another solution, which works better for me...

```
    File file = new File("absolutPathToFile\\FXMLDocument.fxml");
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    Pane root = new Pane();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    try
    {
        root = loader.load(is);

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

I hope it will help someone

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load FXML files from anywhere. One possibility is to use the load command which takes an URL as an argument. You can get that URL easily like this:

```
    try {
        File file = new File("../../FXMLDocument.fxml");
        if (file.canRead()) {
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        } else {
            System.err.println("File does not exist.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think the question wants to fetch the fxml out of the jar rather than as a separate file (in which case [getResource()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19603055/1155209) would be a more applicable example).

Comment: Hmm on re-reading the question, maybe I interpreted it wrong and the asker does actually want to load an fxml file which is not in the jar. Stackoverflow doesn't let me reverse the downvote :(

Comment: I'm Getting Exceptions when I used sth like this:
        File file = new File("../../FXMLDocument.fxml");
        String url = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
        Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(url));
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which exception? Stack trace?

Comment: Sorry for delay... I get this exception: http://pastebin.com/mCHMpqwf
Thanks for your help @mipa

Comment: I updated the example in my answer. You must not use the getClass().getResource() stuff in your case.

Comment: Thanks @mipa, it works :)
all I needed to change is to take "Pane root = new Pane();" outside if statement and in 'if' "root = FXMLLoader.load(url);"