# JavaFX: Invalid URL or resource not found with Maven

Tags: java

I'm creating a JavaFX application and have been using the maven framework alongside it, so naturally, I put the sample.fxml in the resource folder as such:
[image]

Nevertheless, even though my code to reach is literally a carbon-copy of a previous project where it did work, in this instance it refuses to accept that an fxml file exists at that location:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It spits this out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/David/IdeaProjects/FXRpg/target/classes/fxml/sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at sample.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:31)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 20 more
```

The POM file doesn't alter anything either:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaFxApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: how do you start it?
And can you check if target/classes/fxml contains sample.fxml?
If not, then maven did not compile it :) (IntelliJ might have put this into /out instead)

Comment: Is there anything in the pom worth posting, like are you redefining the resource folders?

Comment: Detailed answer here:
[How to reference javafx fxml files in resource folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder)

Comment: @RobertAltena, looking at your link, this is the correct format and should work.

Comment: @OrangeReceptacle the path seems correct for the loader, seems like the sample.fxml is not, could you share the file context as well please

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in an answer from the link shared by @Robert, the path seems correct for the loader, seems like your `sample.fxml` is not. So if you try splitting the loading part of your resource in these steps

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/main.fxml"));
Parent content = loader.load();
```

you will find the failure would be at `load` and not at `getResource`. Probably the right way to debug it. Also to look further what is wrong in the `.fxml`, would need to take a look at the file content.

*Source* - [How to reference javafx fxml files in resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Now I am curious. I have build the project in IntelliJ: Maven, fmxl subdirectory as in the question. The following Main.java worked.

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

If I move the resource file, I get a different error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
```

And for completeness: The POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>JavaFXApplication</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaFXApplication</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```