# Java Illegal Argument Exception while running my java application

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying a build a small video player using java I am getting some errors,please help me fix them.

```js
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Player player = new Player("/Users/name/Desktop/play.mp4");
        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 720,480,Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```js
package sample;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

/**
 * Created by akanksh on 03/11/17.
 */
public class Player extends BorderPane {
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer player;
    MediaView view;
    Pane mpane;
    public Player(String file){

        media = new Media(file);
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        mpane = new Pane();

        mpane.getChildren().add(view);

        setCenter(mpane);
        player.play();

    }
}
```

errors :

[image]

No matter how many times I tried using different videos and different paths,its not working...help needed...

Comment: Try. `file:///Users/name/`

Comment: Thanks so much sir...

Comment: Don't build the URL yourself. Simply prepending `file://` will fail, for example, if there are spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media class needs a valid [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Therefore you need a "schema" for your file such as `file:///Users/...`

Or you could use `new File("/Users/name/Desktop/play.mp4").toURI()`

Answer (score 0):

The media constructor is looking for a URI, not a file path. If you are really specifying a file for the media (i.e. something the user specified on the file system, for example via a `FileChooser`) you should convert the path to a *valid* URI that both has a scheme and properly encodes any invalid characters in the path, such as whitespace.

If you have a `File` object, you simply do this with

```
File file = ... ;
Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
```

If the file is specified as a string, create a file object first (though in any realistic situation you should have a `File` to begin with):

```
public Player(String file){

    media = new Media(new File(file).toURI().toString());
    player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    view = new MediaView(player);
    mpane = new Pane();

    mpane.getChildren().add(view);

    setCenter(mpane);
    player.play();

}
```

Note that in the case where the media is part of the application (instead of being provided on the user's filesystem at run time), you should use a different technique entirely and treat it as a resource. See, for example, [How to reference javafx fxml files in resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder) for accessing resources in JavaFX.