# JavaFX build with shade, Location is required. Where is it looking?

Tags: maven, javafx, maven-shade-plugin

It's still not finding the FXML Location. I've messed with
output Directory and
directory and
the URL going into FXMLLoader to no avail:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/ui.fxml"));
```

**Where is this application looking for resources?**

Directories:

In:

> PROJECT/src/main/java/mypackage/Main.java
>
> PROJECT/src/main/resources/fxml/ui.fxml

Out:

> PROJECT/target/AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> PROJECT/target/AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
>
> PROJECT/target/classes/myPackage/Main.class
>
> PROJECT/target/fxml/ui.fxml

My POM:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.potatospy.NewMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are adding and overriding the `maven-resource-plugin` default behavior?

Comment: @JoséPereda I took that from apache maven resource page. It seemed that I had to specifty my resources directory that way. If I remove the overriding, it still doesnt know the location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the first issue is with your resource:

> Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/ui.fxml"));

If you use `getResource` you have to use an absolute path:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ui.fxml"));
```

There are many questions at StackOverflow about this issue, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603055/3956070) is a very valid reference.

**maven-shade-plugin**

Assuming your `com.potatospy.NewMain` class is a [launcher class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791) that doesn't extend `Application`, and your sources (under `src/main/java/`) are:

- com/potatospy/NewMain.java
- com/potatospy/Main.java
- com/potatospy/UIController.java

and your resources (under `src/main/resources`) are:

- fxml/ui.fxml

If you want to do a shade/fat jar, and you *don't modify* the default maven-resources-plugin, this will work just using the `maven-compile-plugin` and `maven-shade-plugin` plugins from your pom:

```
mvn clean package
```

then you can run your app:

```
java -jar target/AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note that the default resources plugin is applied, and your files are added to `target/classes`:

- target/classes/com/potatospy/NewMain.class
- target/classes/com/potatospy/Main.class
- target/classes/com/potatospy/UIController.class
- target/classes/fxml/ui.fxml

**maven-resource-plugin**

But if you *add* the resources plugin as you have done in your pom, when you run it, you will notice that your files are added to:

- target/classes/com/potatospy/NewMain.class
- target/classes/com/potatospy/Main.class
- target/classes/com/potatospy/UIController.class
- target/fxml/ui.fxml

and when the package is done, the fxml file is not even added to the jar!

If you *need* to include the resources plugin, you'll need something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                   <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that I've added `classes` to the output directory (so the resources are included into it).

Comment: I'm very thankful for your information. I think after having solved this Location null issue several times via other threads, one thing remained... I really did not understand why the fixes worked. Anyway, I'll study your answer to learn as much as possible so I can start assisting others with it!