# Gradle + JavaFX - What is the right way to build the 'resources' directory?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a JavaFX project with Gradle built tool. What is the right way to construct the `src/main/resources` folder so that I could easily access the `*.fxml` and `*.css` by simple line of code:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("xxx.fxml"));
```

I'm using the Gradle plugin and `build.gradle` file for JavaFX in [this tutorial](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Gradle), It has a simple project tree like this:

```
.
├── src.main
|    ├── java
|    |   ├── org.openjfx
|    |   |   ├── MainApp.java
|    |   └── └── FXMLController.java
|    ├── resources
|    |   ├── org.openjfx
|    |   |   ├── scene.fxml
└──  └── └── └── styles.css
```

In this way, the `MainApp.java` can load `scene.fxml` using `getResource("scene.fxml")`.

However, if the `java` and the `resources` directory structures doesn't match, suppose my project tree like this so that I could separate the `fxml` file and `css` file:

```
.
├── src.main
|    ├── java
|    |   ├── org.openjfx
|    |   |   ├── anotherPackage 
|    |   |   |   ├── MainApp.java
|    |   └── └── FXMLController.java
|    ├── resources
|    |   ├── org.openjfx
|    |   |   ├── layouts
|    |   |   |   ├── scene.fxml
|    |   |   ├── styles
└──  └── └── └── └──styles.css
```

Now the `MainApp.java` have to load `scene.fxml` with `getResource("../layouts/scene.fxml")`

I am new to Gradle and JavaFX, and I want to know what is the right way to manage the resources including fxml, CSS, as well as pictures, etc. 

ps. Sorry if I'm not asking the question correctly.

Comment: Note: Don't use `..` when accessing resources via `getResource`.

Comment: It's really up to you how you want to organize your resources. I've seen projects with all FXML files in `fxml` and all CSS files in `styles`, both at the root of the classpath. Personally, I prefer to put my FXML files and CSS files in the same package as the class that uses them (FXML files, by their nature, tend to be highly coupled with one class). In other words, I tend to mirror my package structure in the resources directory. For other resources (e.g. images), it depends on how they're used; organize them how you think is best for your project.

Comment: Thanks, Slaw, It helps a lot. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder?rq=1) that solve my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

iirc, the resource directory structure should mirror the package structure. take a look at https://www.eviltester.com/2017/12/resource-files-for-tests-java-maven.html