# Can't access FXML files in my JavaFX Application using Eclipse?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to run a simple JavaFX file. See my code below.

```js
package com.example.multiplayer_snake;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @SuppressWarnings("exports")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("/Multiplayer_Snake/src/main/resources/com/example/multiplayer_snake/hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

And my folder structure is looking like in this picture

[image]

What I've figured out so far is it has something to do with my absolute path to the .fxml file. If I manually copy the .fxml file into my package and change the path to "hello-view.fxml" I am able to run it. But I don't always want to move/copy the file manually whenever the .fxml file is changed.

```js
"/Multiplayer_Snake/src/main/resources/com/example/multiplayer_snake/hello-view.fxml"
```

But I don't really get why I am still running into errors. Any solutions how to determine the correct path?

Comment: @kleopatra In Maven, it should be configured as a *resource* folder, not a *source* folder.

Comment: Check the contents of `target/classes`. If your FXML file is not in the expected package, something is wrong with your build configuration.

Comment: @James_D yeah, but don't see any mention of maven in the question, maybe being blind :)

Comment: @kleopatra There's a `pom.xml` in the screenshot... So, reasonable assumption? (Mind you, there's an `.iml` file too, which doesn't make much sense in an Eclipse project.)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder

Comment: @James_D ahhh ... thanks for the eye opener :)